# pygame: The sprite class acts like a object class

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, sprite

Im relative new to pygame. Im having a bit of a trouble here. I have searched for documentations but cant figure out why i get this error.

AttributeError: 'Knight' object has no attribute 'rect'

```
class Knight(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pg.image.load("image\\knight.png").convert()

        self.rect = self.rect.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

Here is where i call the class.

```
allSprites = pg.sprite.Group()
player = Knight(0, 0)
allSprites.add(player)

run = True
while run:


    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()


    """ Updating all sprites and the window """
    allSprites.update()
    allSprites.draw()
```

My question is why does pygame thinks my class is an object instead of a sprite class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik77, I don't know pygame, but are you sure this is correct?

```
self.rect = self.rect.get_rect()
```

Have the Sprite class the property "react"?